# How can I draw a shape in a view based on input in the view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, drawing

A very basic version of what I want to do is have a slider and a view within a view controller. The slider signifies the number of sides on a polygon, as you move the slider, a shape is drawn in the subview.

A very simple push in the right direction is all I need. I just am unsure of how the interaction works between view controllers and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  You create a custom view to draw a polygon.  When its `sides` property is set, it calls `setNeedsDisplay` on itself which tells iOS to call `drawRect`.

```
class PolygonView: UIView {
    var sides: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Draw polygon using sides
    }
}
```

In your `ViewController`, update `sides` on the `polygonView` when the slider value changes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var polygonView: PolygonView!

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(sender: UISlider) {
        let sides = Int(sender.value)
        polygonView.sides = sides
    }
}
```

So, when the `slider` is moved, `sliderChanged` will be called.  The value of the `slider` is read and saved to the `sides` property of the `polygonView`.  `didSet` gets called when `sides` is set, and the `polygonView` calls `setNeedsDisplay` on itself.  This tells iOS that the view needs to be drawn, so iOS calls `drawRect` on the `polygonView`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you!